# jQuery animation starts when the elements are on the screen, not when load the page

Tags: jquery, animation

I have a count numbers animation.

This is the code

```
jQuery('.count').each(function () {
        jQuery(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
            Counter: jQuery(this).text()
        }, {
            duration: 5000,
            easing: 'swing',
            step: function (now) {
                jQuery(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
            }
        });
    });
```

But the animation runs when the page load and the content is not visible.
How I can do this?

**Edit**: more expecific question.

> My content are in the middle of the screen, with this I mean that I
>   have to scroll on the page to view my content. Then my question is:
>   how can I make my script animation is delayed until the content is on
>   the screen?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for a lazy loading animation. Not sure but [this plugin](https://github.com/emn178/jquery-lazyload-any) may help you.

Comment: I will try this. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

At first glance I would say that you need to wait for the Document Ready so that it doesn't manipulate the controls until everything is loaded.

See: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

It should be something like this.

```
// Shorthand for $( document ).ready()
$(jQuery('.count').each(function () {
    jQuery(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
      Counter: jQuery(this).text()
    }, {
      duration: 5000,
      easing: 'swing',
      step: function (now) {
        jQuery(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
      }
    });
  });
);
```

Comment: My content are in the middle of the screen, with this I mean that I have to scroll on the page to view my content. Then my question is: how can I make my script animation is delayed until the content is on the screen?